# Force using TLS v1.3

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3, mtls

Im trying to use TLS v1.3 by setting following options:

```
opts->tls_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());

SSL_CTX_set_options(opts->tls_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2);
SSL_CTX_set_options(opts->tls_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
SSL_CTX_set_options(opts->tls_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1);
SSL_CTX_set_options(opts->tls_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1);
SSL_CTX_set_options(opts->tls_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2);
```

The used version is v3 an as I get the following error:

> SSL_connect failed (sslv3 alert handshake failure).

What am I doing wrongly that even though SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 is set v3 is selected ?
Thank you!

I tried to disable TLSv3, TLSv2, TLSv1, TLSv1_1 and TLSv1_2 to enforce using of TLSv1_3, but TLSv3 was selected

**Later Edit**:
I used:

```
opts->tls_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method()); 
SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(opts->tls_ctx, TLS1_3_VERSION);
```

But still TLSv1_2 is used in Client Hello, what might be still wrong ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnACT.png)

Comment: Use SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version

Comment: Use it in conjunction with `SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version` if you want to disable TLSv1.3

Comment: **It's not using SSLv3.** The error text "sslv3 alert handshake failure" means alert code 40, handshake_failure, was _defined_ in SSLv3, and continues to be used in newer/higher protocols. And there are not (and never have been) any TLSv2 or TLSv3. Try connecting with commandline `openssl s_client -connect host:port -tls1_3` with `-trace` in 3.0.x, or 1.1.x if built with that option enabled, or `-state -msg` otherwise to see _exactly_ what is happening. (1.1.0 and lower might need `-servername`, but they don't have TLS1.3 so you can't be using them.)

Comment: I see though the Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)  is present in Client Hello message and the server supports TLS 1.2 is this the reason that seemingly TLS v1.2 is used ?

Comment: Yes, ClientHello in TLS1.3 uses _record_ version 1.0 (0x0301) and _message_ version 1.2 (0x0303) but the real version(s) in supported_versions extension -- this is explained in detail in RFC 8446. Wireshark doesn't know which version applies until it sees the matching ServerHello, which in your case it doesn't, so it guesses wrong.